# How to clear static variables globally in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, static-variables

There a logout feature for my application where I intend to clear all static variables that were created throughout the life of the login session. How can these static variables be cleared globally?

Currently I'm setting all static variable individually to `nil` ex:

`staticVariableSessionID = nil`

Comment: You should probably have a single static that is an instance of a struct. Then you can just assign `nil` to that single static.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 but what if the variables are from different struct. Just curious if there is any solution for scattered static variables. I'm trying to cut down consolidation time.

Comment: No, you, need to assign each variable independently, that is why I suggested you consolidate everything into a single "session" struct

Comment: What a perfect textbook reason to not store user data in static/class variables.

Comment: Thanks guys currently it is a class whose variables are static. Can I straight out convert class to struct without any implications?